# Why use JPA/Hibernate constraint annotation when DB has such constraints

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My DB's tables have attributes, such as length, unique constraints etc. Why keep such constraints using JPA annotations in code (like `@UniqueConstraint`, `length = '25'` etc), since the DB won't accept wrong records and will throw exceptions. Isn't this double-checking? Is it for better exception handling?

Comment: These anotations and properties are only used for DDL purposes i.e. if you are having Hibernate create your schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These anotations and properties are only used for DDL purposes i.e. if you are having Hibernate create your schema.

Validation in Java  can be done by applying bean validation to entities: these allow you to validate before going to the database and enable better error handling as the database is likely to throw a generic exception which will not offer any clean way of identifying the relevant fields:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html